# Awk get specific line?

Tags: awk

I am trying to get a specific line using awk command.

When i do `df -h`, i get :-

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev             16G     0   16G   0% /dev
tmpfs           3.2G  2.7M  3.2G   1% /run
/dev/nvme0n1p2  468G   64G  381G  15% /
tmpfs            16G   77M   16G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs            16G     0   16G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0      100M  100M     0 100% /snap/core/11420
/dev/loop2       56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/2074
```

Using `df -h | awk '{print $2, $3, $4, $5}'` gives me the following output :-

```
Size Used Avail Use%
16G 0 16G 0%
3.2G 2.7M 3.2G 1%
468G 64G 381G 15%
16G 80M 16G 1%
5.0M 4.0K 5.0M 1%
16G 0 16G 0%
```

How can i only get the contents from anything associated with "/" partition whether only using awk or maybe some other command?

Comment: You can prepend it with a grep "/$" where the dollar sign is an anchor for the end of the line. `df -h | grep "/$" | awk '{print $2, $3, $4, $5}'`.

Comment: Why not just `df -h /` ?

Comment: Yes, easier than my suggestion.

Comment: @jhnc Just noticed but your answer prints the following as well :- `Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on`. I did not need this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One awk way would be to filter on field 6. Perhaps:

```
df -h | awk '$6=="/" {print $2, $3, $4, $5}'
```

Alternatively, you could tell `df` to only show /:

```
df -h / | awk '{print $2, $3, $4, $5}'
```

Comment: Thanks. The filtering part is what i needed. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the slash sign in a regular expression before the awk print statement:

```
df -h | awk '$6 ~ /\// {print $2, $3, $4, $5}'
```

Answer (score 0):

A very simple alternative using `sed` simply suppresses normal printing of pattern-space with `-n` and outputs the line ending in `'/'`, e.g.

```
df -h | sed -n '/\/$/p'
```

If you want to squeeze the whitespace between each field of output to a single whitespace delimiter, you can simply pipe to `tr`, e.g.

```
df -h | sed -n '/\/$/p' | tr -s [[:blank:]]
```

**Example Use/Output**

With your `df` output in the file `dat/dfout.txt`, you would have:

```
$ sed -n '/\/$/p' dat/dfout.txt
/dev/nvme0n1p2  468G   64G  381G  15% /
```

Or on my system with the whitespace between each field squeezed to a single whitespace, you have:

```
$ df -h | sed -n '/\/$/p' | tr -s [[:blank:]]
/dev/sdb2 40G 31G 6.5G 83% /
```

**With `awk` and a REGEX**

Another trivial way using `awk` is using a regex match for the same `'/'` at the end, e.g.

```
df -h | awk '$6 ~ /\/$/'
```

(the default rule `print` is applied on match)

The same thing squeezing the whitespace to a single delimiter would be:

```
df -h | awk '$6 ~ /\/$/ {$1 = $1; print}'
```

Where `$1 = $1` forces the fields to be recalculated removing excess whitespace, but then an explicit `print` is needed as more than the default rule is provided.